# Oracle APEX Security Tips?

Tags: security, oracle-apex

I have a suite of Oracle Apex based applications due to have a security test. Does anyone have any tips on what I should look for to tighten things up?

Answer (score 1):

The thing with Apex applications is that the underlying code is all PL/SQL, so it is no surprise that the major class of vulnerability affecting Apex application is SQL Injection.

You need to make sure that you do not use substitution variables (e.g. &P1_TEST.) as these almost always lead to exploitable injection. When they are used within PL/SQL begin/end blocks the injection is very "powerful" as an attacker can specify an arbitrary number of PL/SQL statements.

Many Apex apps use dynamic SQL (where a query is constructed in a string and then executed), either through direct calls to EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or through Apex FUNCTION_RETURNING_SQL blocks. Dynamic SQL is almost always a bad idea.

You'll also find quite a bit of Cross-Site Scripting in Apex apps, where input from users, or from queries run against the database is not escaped. The various Apex reports provide settings to enable escaping but these may not have been chosen when the report was defined.

Also consider the access-control model and ensure all the pages are protected with appropriate authorisation schemes. Do not use the APEX_APPLICATION_FILES table if you're storing uploads as that doesn't protect against unauthenticated downloads.

Hope that helps, and good luck!

Comment: (disclosure) I work for a company that produces an automated security assessment tool for Oracle Apex applications (https://secure.recx.co.uk/apexsec)

Comment: Thanks for this I was a victim of using substitution variables within the PL/SQL begin/end blocks. Do you have a reference on how to do this securely?

Comment: Re the part about FUNCTION_RETURNING_SQL and "dynamic SQL is almost always a bad idea". It is perfectly safe as long as you ensure that you use bind variables and not concatenation to associate user inputs with the SQL.